# Can not measure the file size using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, file

I have one issue while i am uploading my file into local folder using Angular.js and PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.regdoc.$touched && billdata.regdoc.$invalid }">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="regdoc" id="regdoc"  ng-model="regfile" ngf-pattern="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ngf-select="onRegFileSelect($file);" >
</div>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.onRegFileSelect=function(files){
        //console.log('docs details',files);
        regDocURL=files;
        $scope.firstDocs='';
}
if($scope.firstDocs ==''){
    var regDocs=regDocURL;
    var curnum=(Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
    newRegPath=curnum+"_"+ regDocs.name;
    Upload.rename(regDocs, newRegPath);
    var regdocsdata={'image':regDocs};
    fileData.push(regdocsdata);
}else{
    newRegPath=$scope.firstDocs;
}
console.log('file',fileData);
$scope.upload=Upload.upload({
        url: 'php/uploadAll.php',
        method:'POST',
        file: fileData
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('file succ',data);
}).error(function(data, status) {
        console.log('file error',data);
});
```

> uploadAll.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    // print_r($_FILES['file']);
     for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']['name']);$i++){

         print_r($_FILES['file']['size'][$i]['image']);
         /*$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]['image'];
         $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'][$i]['image'];
         $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]['image'];
         $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'][$i]['image'];   
         $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf","ppt","docx");        
         if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
              header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
              $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
              print_r($errors);
              return;
         }
         if($file_size > 2097152){
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
            $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
            print_r($errors);
            return;
         }               
         if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../upload/".$file_name);
            echo " uploaded file: " . "upload/" . $file_name.$file_size;
         }else{
            print_r($errors);
         }*/
     }
}else{
    $errors= array();
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    $errors[]="No file found";
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

Here my problem is when i am uploading the big file lets say one file is more than `5/6 mb` the file size showing `0` so that i can not upload that file into folder but when i am uploading file related `kb` the file size is easily measuring.another problem is when uploading big file its true that file is not uploading to the folder but this `if(empty($errors)==true)` from above file is executing which should not.Here i need to calculate the file size and upload it accordingly.Please help me.

Comment: Try to print contents of this key: `$_FILES['file']['error']`. Error messages explained: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: It's most likey that you have upload limit. Check this answer and try to change your settings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @Stalinko : Yes, you are right.I knew it later.Maximum file size has to set in `php.ini` file.Its by default `2mb`.